Fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 Text Editor asking for password on every text file copied from old laptop
I've got a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04. I copied all my documents from my old laptop onto a USB, and then pasted them all into /home/colin/... on my new laptop. For every single text or csv file, the Text Editor from Ubuntu 24.04 is asking for a password before I can edit the file. However, I can open the same file in LibreOffice Calc or Writer and there is no password requirement, so it appears to be something specific to Text Editor. If I create a new file in Text Editor, save it, close it, and reopen it, a password is not required, so it also appears to be something specific to having copied the text files across from the USB.
Any idea what is going on here?
EDIT: It... just stopped. The only thing I did was create a new temporary text file in my Documents folder, save it, and reopen it, and suddenly I'm no longer getting asked for the password for any of my text files. I'm going to leave the question up, as this was very strange and may affect other people.

When you open the new Text Editor it opens previously opened files. If you have opened a text file that needed the admin password before, it may be trying to open that file again and ask for the password. You can click Cancel and close the tab of the offending file.

I got the same issue. It seems that the text editor application automatically opens all previously opened text files as other tabs, unless explicitly closed as tabs.
One of the file I previously opened required root access to be read. Therefore, upon closing the text editor tab corresponding to the file requiring root access, it solved the issue.

This makes sense and is probably the source of the issue. It is hardly unusual to have to look at a couple of root-level text files when setting up a fresh OS. I must have left one open in a tab in the text editor and then explicitly closed it while trying to work out what was going wrong. Thanks for the response.

You can take the ownership of the  your old data or any directory by the following command:
sudo chown -R username /the-path-to-directory

In your case, use this command:
sudo chown -R colin /home/colin

When we assume that you have a directory under /home/colin and this directory called my-data as example, you can apply this command to take the ownership over this specifid directory:
sudo chown -R colin /home/colin/my-data

or
sudo chown -R colin ~/my-data


Apologies, I probably should have made it clear in the question that my username is colin, so /home/colin/... is already owned by me. I think the other answer has hit the nail on the head.

no problem I mean the old files that placed in your new home directory. if you face the ownership issue, you can use this command
